# validation of persistent ignorant domain objects

Tags: entity-framework, validation, architecture, domain-driven-design

I want to know how to check if Domain Object is in right state while saving it.
If Object has persistent information - it is clear as for instance I can check Order's amount in its Save method. However persistent ignorant objects don't have Save method. They just have data and behavior. Should I rely on developers' accuracy or I need to check all entities graphs somehow before saving it in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm not understanding you right.

I'm not sure how you get an "ignorant" object.  That seems to run against the core tenet of encapsulation. The only way to modify an object's state should be through its interface.  It's the interface's responsibility to ensure any updates to state are valid.  So, to your example, you shouldn't need to check the amount in the `save()` operation (assuming here "save" means persist).  It should be updated as a consequence of e.g. calling `addProduct()` (or something similar - i.e. adding item to order updates amount).

Whether an object is persistent or transitory is irrelevant - it should *always* encapsulate state update through its interface.

Hope that helps - apologies if I've misunderstood.

Comment: thanks for answer. By persistent ignorant I mean that object doesn't know anything about database (no save method, repositories don't appear in it's behavior methods). So object's behavior is only change it's state in memory and nothing else. Hmm, you wrote that changing object's state occurs in behavior methods only, does it mean that I need to make all properties read only to strictly restrict object's modifications outside the object. Hmm, such logic may produce a lot of methods in the object. :)

Comment: OK now I understand 'persistent ignorant'.  Makes sense, and in line with DDD guidance.  Properties don't need to be read-only though.  But the write accessor should ensure that any request to update state is valid.  Am guessing you're using c# (since q is tagged entity-framework).  In which case you just need to add validation logic to property `set` accessors.  Shouldn't mean adding a lot of new methods (unless, again, I'm misunderstanding). hth.

Comment: Ok, it is clear, thanks. I can't use setters for validation as it is generated by EF POCO generator. In this scenario I can make required properties (properties that can harm object integrity) read only and change them through behavior methods. Ok, thank you, here is your points :).

Comment: You're welcome - and thanks :-).  Surprised (and disappointed) by your comments on EF though.  Haven't used it personally.  But sounds like it's encouraging the "anaemic domain model" anti-pattern - which isn't good.

Comment: Hello, I know that it is better to develop pure domain logic from beginning, however I have existing database and want to practice DDD. I don't think that you are right about encouraging the 'anaemic domain model' as my domain object is POCO. It is your choice in adding business logic to domain objects (only real object's behaviors) or in services. :) –

Comment: Yes and no.  Evans is pretty clear in the DDD book: put the behaviour with the object it belongs to.  Only create a Domain Service if the behaviour really doesn't fit with any single object (class).  Anyway - good luck however you proceed.